# Python 3.5 xlsxwriter assistance

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can can I convert "Daily Return" and "MTD Return" into percentages if I am using xlsxwriter?

*Current code being used with xlsxwriter

```
worksheet.write('B10', df2.loc[4,["NAV"]])
worksheet.write('C10', df2.loc[4,["Daily_DVA"]])
worksheet.write('D10', df2.loc[4,["MTD_DVA"]])
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzAfe.png)

Also how am I able to add colors to the "Trading Activity" and "Performance Data" columns along with making the text bold like the following image attached? I would also like to keep the text centered as well.

*Current code being used with xlsxwriter

```
worksheet.merge_range('A2:B2', 'Trading Activity', center_format)
worksheet.merge_range('A8:D8', 'Performance Data', center_format)
```

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70u9J.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add appropriate formats. Like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a format for percentages.
percent_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})

worksheet.write('B1', .5)
worksheet.write('B2', .5, percent_format)

# Add a format for a merged range.
merge_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'border': 1,
    'align': 'center',
    'valign': 'vcenter',
    'fg_color': '#16DDFF'})

worksheet.merge_range('B4:D4', 'Trading Activity', merge_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I would point out that those formats are references, so if you're editing the same format for different type cells, the last one will be the one that is applied to all cells that referenced the same `var`.

Comment: Correct. If the OP needs three different color merge formats then they will have to create 3 different format object. This is [documented](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#modifying-formats) in XlsxWriter and all of the examples are structured like that but it can still be surprising to new users.